# Cannot deploy application to glassfish server

Tags: deployment, glassfish

[image]

Got the above error when trying to deploy to glassfish server.

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

This is the error.

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [pintar_detection] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'filter'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":param-name}' is expected.. Please see server.log for more details.

Need to solve this ASAP.

Comment: *Magnifier please !* Paste the error instead of screenshot here.

Comment: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [pintar_detection] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'filter'. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":param-name}' is expected.. Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: Please add your `web.xml` to the question.

Comment: Please also upload your server.log. Either the deployment errors, or paste it into something like pastebin.com and add a link.

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with the way you defined a filter in your web.xml. To be more precise the error should be somewhere in an <init-param> of the filter. You should provide your web.xml to have more info.

Comment: @jjd: you point at the correct issue. It's one of the configuration issue in web.xml. I have resolved this issue.